# Changing the color of a teapot sometimes not working

Tags: c, opengl, glut

This program should allow the user to select the material of a teapot, that will change dynamically.So I made a menu.
I use setRGB (declared in a utility file) to set the color of an array of 3 GLfloat's.
createMenu just creates the menu reading the voices from a va_list.
setMaterial sets the material, according to the value passed with an enumeration:

```
typedef enum
{
    BlackPlastic= 0,
    Brass,
    Bronze,
    Chrome,
    Copper,
    Gold,
    Peweter,
    Silver,
    PolishedSilver
}MaterialType;
```

*I will omit the body of the functions that I have tested since they work*:

```
int createMenu(void (*callback) (int),int key, const char* const first, ...)
{
    // creates a menu, the number of entries depends on the list length,
    // the value starts from zero
}

void setRGB( GLfloat* color, GLfloat red, GLfloat green, GLfloat blue)
{
    // Sets the color
}


void setMaterial (GLfloat** material, MaterialType type)
{
    // Sets the material color (ambient, diffuse, specular).
}
```

That's the whole program.My fear here is that I am doing something wrong so that the teapot isn't drawn because OpenGL enters in an invalid state.
*The problem is that sometimes I don't see the teapot drawn in the window, I just get a black window*.Incredibly sometimes work and I see the teapot, and I am able to change the material colors.

```
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
#include "utility.h"
#include <stdlib.h>


GLfloat width=500, height=500;
GLfloat** material;
GLfloat light[3][3]= { {1,1,0}, {1,0.5,0}, {1,0,0} };


void menuCallback (int choice)
{
    setMaterial((GLfloat**)material, choice);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void init()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-width/2, width/2, -height/2, height/2, 1, 1000);

    material= malloc(4*sizeof(GLfloat*));
    for(GLuint i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        material[i]=malloc(3*sizeof(GLfloat));
    }

    setRGB(material[3], 1, 1, 0);
    setMaterial(material, BlackPlastic);
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);

    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, material[0] );
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, material[1]);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, material[2]);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, material[3] );

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light[0]);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light[1]);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light[2]);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glutSolidTeapot(100);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
}

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(width,height);
    glutCreateWindow(*argv);
    createMenu(menuCallback, GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON, "Black Plastic", "Brass", "Bronze", "Chrome", "Copper", "Gold", "Peweter", "Silver", "Polished Silver", NULL);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're drawing a solid teapot? I presume you enabled depth testing (though your glutInitDisplayMode lacks the depth buffer bit). Anyway, you should probably also clear the depth buffer. Right now you're clearing only the color buffer

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Change it into

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: I'm not using depth, I'm making all 2D.Anyways if I try what you said I still have that problem.This is the ortho: glOrtho(-width/2, width/2, -height/2, height/2, 1, 1000); The line glEnable(GL_DEPTH) was just a mistake, I've deleted it from the code now, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: Oh, I didn't notice this as first, but: If your teapot is scaled to size 100, then the near clip plane of ortho will likely cull it. So either make your ortho z range -1000, 1000 or so, or just use reasonably small values for the projection extents. They don't have to be the viewport size, you know. Also as another tip: Put all OpenGL code into the display function only. Don't set the projection in the resize handler. You'll have to move it to the display function anyway, sooner or later (as soon as you want to overlay a HUD, text or similar).

Comment: By "Put OpenGL code into the display function only" : Do you mean the code that I put into the init() function? I've put it there just because I need to execute it once, is that wrong?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: What makes you think you need to execute it only once? OpenGL is a state machine, and as soon as your programs become larger, it's getting more and more difficult to keep track of state changes. It's far easier and cleaner to just set all the required state right when you need it. Of course the allocation of material arrays is a one time operation. But why are you doing that dynamically in the first place?

Comment: That's a simple program and I'm sure I'll not need to change these things.I track just the window's size.But talking about the glOrtho, I changed it to -1000,1000 it doesn't work.